# Adding fonts in Qualtrics

Tags: html, css, fonts, qualtrics

Is it possible to add custom fonts in CSS in Qualtrics; i.e. exotic fonts that are not already proposed (Arial, ComicSansMS, CourrierNew, Georgia, Lucida…)?

I've implemented a `<link rel="stylesheet'…>` directing to an external stylesheet referring to custom fonts, but it doesn't work. Inline CSS works for other fonts, but not for non-websafe fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put in the first lines a link tag to the .css:
       `<link href="https://foo.com/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
2. Create the .css folder that contains:

```css
    @font-face {
              font-family: 'fontOne';
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
              src: local('fontOne'), url(http://foo.com/fonts/fontOne.woff) format('woff');
            }
```

3. Refer inline as `<p style="font-family:'fontOne';">YourText</p>`